# Model navigation drawer not covering statusbar. How to fix that?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose

I implemented a navigation drawer using jetpack compose. It looks like this

[image]

**But it's not like the usual navigation drawer. it's not covering the status bar. I want this status bar like that one**

[image]

**here is my model navigation drawer code**

```
@Composable
fun Drawer(scope: CoroutineScope, scaffoldState: ScaffoldState, navController: NavController) {
    val items = listOf(
        NavDrawerItem.Home,
        NavDrawerItem.Music,
        NavDrawerItem.Movies,
        NavDrawerItem.Books,
        NavDrawerItem.Profile,
        NavDrawerItem.Settings
    )
    val item1 = "Logout"
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo1),
            contentDescription = R.drawable.logo1.toString(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp)
        )
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(5.dp)
        )
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
        items.forEach { item ->
            DrawerItem(item = item, selected = currentRoute == item.route, onItemClick = {
                navController.navigate(item.route) {
                    navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                        popUpTo(route) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    
                    restoreState = true
                }
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
                }
            })
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(5.dp)
        )
        Logout(scope, scaffoldState)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(
            text = "Developed by CrazyBot Studio",
            color = Color.Black,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(12.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}
```

**Is this possible on jetpack compose if yes the how can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Jetnews code](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/JetnewsApp.kt):

In your `Activity` you can use something like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            YourComposeTheme {
                ProvideWindowInsets {
                    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
                    val darkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
                    SideEffect {
                        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(Color.Transparent, darkIcons = darkIcons)
                    }
                    //SimpleScaffoldWithTopBar()
                    //Your Scaffold or Drawer code
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It showing the error "Unresolved reference: rememberSystemUiController" how to fix that?

Comment: @Tanjimahmed You have to add the accompanist library provided by google: https://github.com/google/accompanist

Comment: yes I added this dependence "implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0'"

Comment: @Tanjimahmed I am not able to reproduce you issue. https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/v0.17.0/systemuicontroller/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/systemuicontroller/SystemUiController.kt#L162

Comment: I solved the problem but now the extra space for status bar is gone

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code in your Activity file.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        makeStatusBarTransparent()
    }

private fun makeStatusBarTransparent() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

    }
```

I hope it works for you!!!

Comment: it hiding my tool bar.

Comment: @Tanjimahmed  I have updated the answer please have a look.